# Need help to understand how this part of the code works

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making the platformer in Unity2d. So there are gonna be platforms that you can jump on, or jump off. I tried different ways to check platform under. And i found this code. It works well to detect is there anything under you, but i cant understand this part of it.
Object "Player" has special trigger that detects the layer under. This trigger works with this code. When something enters the trigger, it detects the layer of it. And if the layer is correct while its in trigger, it returns true. When it exit the trigger it returns false.

Here's the code that I don't understand:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class scr_GroundCheck: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayerMask;
    [SerializeField] private platformLayerMask;
    public bool isGrounded;

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        // This is what I don't understand.
        isGrounded = collision != null && (((1 << collision.gameObject.layer) & groundLayerMask) != 0);
    }
}
```

I cant understand how how exactly this line works.

Comment: Please review _all_ information at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. The two biggest problems with this question are that you didn't provide any code (images don't count), and you are asking the community to walk you through the design and implementation of someone else's code, which is really too broad/unfocused a question for the site anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it is this part of the line that is confusing:

> ((1 << collision.gameObject.layer) & groundLayerMask)

You could try to read up in "bit fields", first google hit is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

What's happening here is that "groundLayerMask" is what its name implies, a binary mask which specifies zero, one or any combination of 32 possible mask (since an enum usually derives from int which is 32 bits), while "collision.gameObject.layer" is an integer referring to just *one* possible single layer/bit.

So "1 << collision.gameObject.layer" converts from a position (0,1,2,...) to a single bit (1,2,4,8,...), like this:

```
0 -> 0000 0001 = 1
1 -> 0000 0010 = 2
2 -> 0000 0100 = 4
3 -> 0000 1000 = 8
```

and so on

And so "((1 << collision.gameObject.layer) & groundLayerMask)" will be zero if groundLayerMask does not contain the layer collision.gameObject.layer refers to, and non-zero if it does.